# How not to see the 0 values for Hours when input is 24 hr or 48 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, null

```
DECLARE @Hours AS INT
DECLARE @SubtractDate AS DATETIME

SET @Hours=24 /* User input to have hours */
SET @SubtractDate=DATEADD(hh,@Hours,GETDATE()) - GETDATE()

if @Hours>=24 


SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',@SubtractDate))+ ' Day(s) ' +
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate))+ ' Hour(s) 'AS [Result]

Else 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate))+ ' Hour(s) ' AS [Result]
```

EDIT: copy pasted from comments.

when input:

```
SET @Hours=24 /* User input to have hours /
```

Desired Result would be: `1 Day` instead, it shows: `1 Day(s) 0 Hour(s)`

Also: when input:

```
SET @Hours=48 / User input to have hours */
```

Desired Result would be: `2 Days` instead, it shows: `2 Day(s) 0 Hour(s)`

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want.  (2) Decide what database you are using.  The code is not MySQl code.

Comment: ....this code is most likly to be SQL-server SQL.. SQL-server supports the functions DATEADD, DATEGET, DATEDIFF and DATEPART and declaring user variables the way you did and used them.

Comment: when input: SET @Hours=24 /* User input to have hours */ Desired Result would be:  1 Day instead right now it is showing: 1 Day(s) 0 Hour(s)...................................... Also: when input: SET @Hours=48 /* User input to have hours */ Desired Result would be:  2 Days instead right now it is showing: 2 Day(s) 0 Hour(s)

Comment: It is SQL SERVER but I am not connecting to any database

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE to check if the hour part should be used.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @Hours AS INT
DECLARE @SubtractDate AS DATETIME

SET @Hours=24/* User input to have hours */
SET @SubtractDate=DATEADD(hh,@Hours,GETDATE()) - GETDATE()

if @Hours>=24


SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',@SubtractDate))+ ' Day(s) ' +

  + 

  CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) > 0
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) + ' Hour(s)' 
    ELSE '' 
  END 

  AS [Result]

Else 
  SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate))+ ' Hour(s) '
  AS [Result]
```

**Result SET @Hours=24**

```
|    Result |
|-----------|
| 1 Day(s)  |
```

**Result SET @Hours=25**

```
|             Result |
|--------------------|
| 1 Day(s) 1 Hour(s) |
```

**Result SET @Hours=48**

```
|    Result |
|-----------|
| 2 Day(s)  |
```

Edit: output formatted

**Query**

```
DECLARE @Hours AS INT
DECLARE @SubtractDate AS DATETIME

SET @Hours=1/* User input to have hours */
SET @SubtractDate=DATEADD(hh,@Hours,GETDATE()) - GETDATE()

if @Hours>=24


SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',@SubtractDate)) = 1
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',@SubtractDate))+ ' Day '

    WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',@SubtractDate)) >= 2 
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',@SubtractDate))+ ' Days '
  END

  + 

  CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) > 0
    THEN CASE
           WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) = 1 
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) + ' Hour'

           WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) >= 2 
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) + ' Hours'           
         END
    ELSE '' 
  END 

  AS [Result]

Else 
  SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) > 0
    THEN CASE
           WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) = 1 
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) + ' Hour'

           WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) >= 2 
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(hh,@SubtractDate)) + ' Hours'           
         END
    ELSE '' 
  END 
  AS [Result]
```

**Result SET @Hours=1**

```
| Result |
|--------|
| 1 Hour |
```

**Result SET @Hours=2**

```
| Result  |
|---------|
| 2 Hours |
```

**Result SET @Hours=24**

```
| Result |
|--------|
| 1 Day  |
```

**Result SET @Hours=25**

```
|             Result |
|--------------------|
| 1 Day 1 Hour       |
```

**Result SET @Hours=26**

```
|        Result |
|---------------|
| 1 Day 2 Hours |
```

**Result SET @Hours=48**

```
|    Result |
|-----------|
| 2 Days    |
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I put SET @Hours=65 the result is: 2 Day(s) 17 Hour(s)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is 2 days 17 hours is fine but how could I make the out put 1 Day 1 Hour instead of 1 Day(s) 1 Hour(s) sorry for being so fussy-- any help would be really appriciated

Comment: @rumana Should be correct  2 * 24 = 48.. 65 - 48 = 17 ...72 hours should be 3 Days

Comment: Oh if it 1 day and 1 hour you want to display as `1 Day 1 Hour` instead off `1 Day(s) 1 Hour(s)`

Comment: Yes please. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hi Many Thanks. the only issue is when using 1 as input [SET @Hours=1/* User input to have hours */] the result is still being :1 Hour(s)

Comment: @rumana yes the else statement was executed there wasnt anny formatting.. updated the last query now there is formatting.